# Is it possible to have edit in place in a KendoUI ListView for each field separately?

Tags: listview, telerik, kendo-ui, edit-in-place

For instance if I have a ListView of items with a Title and a Description, is it possible to to edit each field separately using KendoUI?

If so, is it possible to have that using KendoUI MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

Yo mate

I am not sure but isn't [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/editing.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @XMR, thanks for your reply but in that example the edit is for all fields and not for each one separately :p